# IEnumerable.GroupBy not grouping

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, equality

I am having trouble with using of GroupBy extension in .NET (4.5, no matter if VB.NET or C#. Exaples are in C#). Here is the situation:

2 example classes:

```
public class Office : IEquatable<Office>
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Stuff { get; set; }

    // Compare by values
    public bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Office)
        {
            Office cmp = (Office) obj;
            bool result = true;
            result &= cmp.Id == this.Id;
            result &= cmp.Name == this.Name;
            result &= cmp.Stuff == this.Stuff;
            return result;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    // Hashcode by values
    public int GetHashCode()
    {
        var obj = new { Id = this.Id, Name = this.Name, Stuff = this.Stuff };
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }

    // IEquatable uses overriden Equals implementation
    bool IEquatable<Office>.Equals(Office other)
    {
        return this.Equals(other);
    }
}

public class Company
{
    public Office Office { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Class Office has overriden equality comparison functions and implements IEquatable interface, in which case (as I understand) Default EqualityComparer uses my impementation of Equals.

Now I want to group a list of companies according to offices which they occupy, like this:

```
        List<Company> companies = new List<Company>();
        Office office1 = new Office();
        office1.Id = 1;
        office1.Name = "Office";
        office1.Stuff = "Stuff";

        Office office2 = new Office();
        office2.Id = 1;
        office2.Name = "Office";
        office2.Stuff = "Stuff";

        Company date1 = new Company();
        date1.Office = office1;
        date1.Name = "Date 1";

        Company date2 = new Company();
        date2.Office = office2;
        date2.Name = "Date 2";

        companies.Add(date1);
        companies.Add(date2);

        IEnumerable<IGrouping<Office, Company>> grouping = companies.GroupBy(x => x.Office);

        Console.WriteLine("Groups: " + grouping.Count()); // returns 2!!!
        Console.WriteLine("Equals: " + office1.Equals(office2)); // returns true
        Console.WriteLine("Hash 1: " + office1.GetHashCode()); // returns 2067935290
        Console.WriteLine("Hash 2: " + office2.GetHashCode()); // returns 2067935290

        IEqualityComparer cmp = EqualityComparer<Office>.Default;
        Console.WriteLine("Comparer: " + cmp.Equals(office1, office2)); // returns true
```

You can see that each company has different Office object, but in the logic of my application these objects are considered equal. Therefore calling `office1.Equals(office2)` returns true, object hashcodes are equal and using `EqualityComparer<Office>.Default`'s function `Equals` also returns true.

Now the mystery is why calling GroupBy office returns two groups, even though offices are "equal". Documentation states that key's Default EqualityComparer is used (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx).

Thanks for any help~

Comment: You must properly override `GetHashCode()` method.

Comment: You probably didn't want the bitwise `&=` operator either, just use && for combining boolean values, that way it can short-circuit the evaluation if possible.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by word "properly". Class `Office` overrides this function and Hashcodes of both `office1` and `office2` are equal.

Comment: `GetHashCode` on an anonymous type will hash and combine all of its members. It's fine, guys.

Comment: For your overload of `GroupBy` (from MSDN) `The default equality comparer Default is used to compare keys.`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan well that's what I mentioned in the last paragraph. And according to the MSDN, if a class implements IEquatable, the Default equality comparer uses that implementation. I still don't see what is wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default comparer is calling `Object.GetHashCode` and `IEquatable<Office>.Equals`.

This isn't working for you because you are *hiding* the `GetHashCode()` member, not overriding it.

Your `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods should be changed:

```
public **override** bool Equals(object obj)
public **override** int GetHashCode()
```

Comment: Bingo. Thank you! Adding `override` keyword fixed the thing.

Comment: The suggested method just overriding of equality members. `IEquatable<T>` nothing deal in this scenario.

Comment: @Hamlet I'm not sure what you mean. `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` *will* use `IEquatable<T>.Equals` over `Object.Equals` if available.

Comment: I mean if you have overrided the equality members of class then there is no necessary to implement `IEquatable<T>`. Also to have different behaviors in `IEquatable<T>.Equals` and in overriden `Equals` is already doomed.

Comment: Gotcha. The only difference in most cases should be in performance.

Answer (score 2):

Jan, you can set modifier `override` at inherited methods `GetHashCode` and `Equals` then count Groups equals 1.That is because, when Offices comparers, call method `Equal` by Default and call not method `Equal` contains in `Office` class. Correct, example:

```
public class Office : IEquatable<Office>
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Stuff { get; set; }

    // Compare by values
    public override  bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Office)
        {
            Office cmp = (Office) obj;
            bool result = true;
            result &= cmp.Id == this.Id;
            result &= cmp.Name == this.Name;
            result &= cmp.Stuff == this.Stuff;
            return result;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    // Hashcode by values
    public override int  GetHashCode()
    {
        var obj = new { Id = this.Id, Name = this.Name, Stuff = this.Stuff };
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }

    // IEquatable uses overriden Equals implementation
    bool IEquatable<Office>.Equals(Office other)
    {
        return this.Equals(other);
    }
}
```